# Error: Humanoid is not a valid member of model

Tags: lua, roblox

I'm making a tower defense game, towers fight enemies. Towers have range and if they find and enemy near its range, it attacks it. My problem is that my tower start killing enemies normally, then gets this error message "Humanoid is not a valid member of ".

The tower script to find the closest enemy

```
local Tower = script.Parent
local enemies = game.Workspace.enemies
local range = 20
local target= nil
local Animator = Tower.Humanoid.Animator
local Attack = Animator:LoadAnimation(Tower.AttackAnim)

     function nearestenemy()
         for i, enemy in ipairs(enemies:GetChildren()) do
             local distance = (Tower.HumanoidRootPart.Position - enemy.HumanoidRootPart.Position).Magnitude
        
             if (distance < range) and (enemy.Humanoid.Health > 0) then
                  target = enemy
                 range = distance
             end 
         end
    
         range = 20
    
          if target then
             return target.Humanoid
         else
             return nil
         end
     end

     while true do
         local victim = nearestenemy()
         if victim then
             victim:TakeDamage(3)
         end
         task.wait(.5)
     end
```

the enemies despawn after 0.6 seconds of dying

Please Help!

I looked into the forums, nothing worked
I made the tower not target dead enemies, no change
I Checked if the enemies even had a humanoid, nothing worked (The specific enemy is cloned from an orginal clone enemy with a humanoid)

Comment: Are you sure you're reffering to the right model? Do the models have a humanoid?

Comment: Yes, they have a humanoid and the first few enemies on the track die before the error occurs

Comment: by far of what i saw, when the tower cant target anything and an enemy gets on its range, it causes the error

Answer (score 0):

```
local _,victim = pcall(nearestenemy)
```